# Styling nested table position

Tags: html, css

I need to have a card as below:
[image]

So I wrote the below code

```css
.box {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    padding: 40px 25px;
    background: #FFF;
    max-width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.box.ofh {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*Ribbon */
.half-circle-ribbon {
  background: #EA4335;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
  border: 1px dashed #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #EA4335;
}

.price {
    width: 58%;
    height: 100%;

    color: #eef122;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align: right;
}

.price .cents {
    margin-left: -.5em;
    position: relative;
    top: -.625em;
    font-size: .5em;
}

.fit-picture {
    width: 250px;
}

thead,
tfoot {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
  <!-- Ribbon -->
  <div class="box ofh">
    <div class="half-circle-ribbon"><span class="price">350.<span class="cents">99</span></span></div>

    <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">كرت صنف</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 250px;">
                <img class="fit-picture"
                src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg"
                alt="Grapefruit slice atop a pile of other slices">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 750px; text-align: right;">

                <table dir="rtl" style="width: 100%; border: 1px 1px 1px 1px solid #333; position: relative; top:5%; right: 5%;"></table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>الصنف:</td>
                        <td>nested table C2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>المورد:</td>
                        <td>nested table</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

But I got the below:
[image]

I think the problem is in this line:

```css
<table dir="rtl" style="width: 100%; border: 1px 1px 1px 1px solid #333; position: relative; top:5%; right: 5%;"></table>
```

Why, should not be the position of the nested table be referenced to the parent element, which is in this case the `td` of the first table?!

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing one `<table>` tag in between.

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 40px 25px;
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.box.ofh {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*Ribbon */
.half-circle-ribbon {
  background: #ea4335;
  color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #ea4335;
}

.price {
  width: 58%;
  height: 100%;

  color: #eef122;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: right;
}

.price .cents {
  margin-left: -0.5em;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.625em;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

.fit-picture {
  width: 250px;
}

.table-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
   margin-top:-6.5rem;
}

.nest-table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

thead,
tfoot {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- Ribbon -->
<div class="box ofh">
  <div class="half-circle-ribbon">
    <span class="price">350.<span class="cents">99</span></span>
  </div>

  <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">كرت صنف</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 250px">
        <img
          class="fit-picture"
          src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg"
          alt="Grapefruit slice atop a pile of other slices"
        />
      </td>
      <td style="width: 750px; text-align: right">
        <table
          dir="rtl"
          style="
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px 1px 1px 1px solid #333;
            position: relative;
            top: 5%;
            right: 5%;
          "
        ></table>
        <table class="table-2">
          <tbody style="width: 100%">
            <tr class="nest-table">
              <td style="margin-left: 30%">nested table C2</td>
              <td>الصنف:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="nest-table">
              <td style="margin-left: 30%">nested table</td>
              <td>المورد:</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```